# Issues while validating snapcraft.yaml: '/home/Desktop/xxx-snappy/folder/' is not of type 'object'

Tags: yaml, snapcraft

the below is my snap file. Can you explain me how to use copy plugin. I just want to copy the file form one folder to another.

```
name: xxx
version: 6.0
# The vendor for the snap (replace 'Vendor <email@example.com>')
vendor: xxx@gmail.com
summary: a sample package
description: blah blah blah
icon: icon.png

parts:
 glue:
 plugin: copy
 source: /home/Desktop/xxx-snappy/folder/
 files: 
 .: /bin/xxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you're using snapcraft v1.x, is that correct? Assuming so, this YAML looks good except for the indentation within parts; it's not actually valid YAML. Try this:

```
name: xxxx
version: 6.0
# The vendor for the snap (replace 'Vendor <email@example.com>')
vendor: xxx@gmail.com
summary: a sample package
description: blah blah blah 
icon: icon.png

parts:
  glue:
    plugin: copy
    source: /home/Desktop/xxx-snappy/folder/
    files: 
      .: /bin/folder
```